# OData Simple Client: Linked collection for type [Type] not found

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, odata

I have xamarin forms application. I use odata simple client to manipulate app database.

I am trying to add data to many-to-many tables.

This is my first entity

```
    public class Genre : BaseGenre
    {
        List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

And my other one

```
    public class User : BaseUser
    {
        List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    }
```

And this the function I am trying to link them

```
    public async void AddGenresAsnyc(User u, List<Genre> Genres)
    {
        u.Genres = Genres;
        try {
            //await client.For<User> (CollectionName).Key(u).LinkEntryAsync(us => us.Genres, Genres);
            await client.For<User> (CollectionName).Key(u.id).Set(u).UpdateEntriesAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Exception ex = e;
        }
    }
```

The first one, linkentryasync throws the exception

> Number of parameter does not match expected count.

And the second one throws

> Linked collection for type [Genre] not found

Any help would be great. I am stuck at work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you send me a metadata file for your service to vagif.abilov at gmail? I can have a look.

Comment: I did, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One immediate thing that you need to change is make properties Genre.Users and User.Genres public. Simple.OData.Client uses reflection to assign property values and is not capable of assigning values for private properties/fields. I tested your code with the schema you sent me and as long as the properties were public, the request went through.

Regarding the next example (using LinkEntryAsync), if you want to update links in a single call, you should use UpdateEntryAsync, because LinkEntryAsync does it for a single link. So either use:

```
var user = await client.For<User>("ApiUser").Key(1).FindEntryAsync();
user.Genres = genres;
await client.For<User>("ApiUser").Key(user).Set(user).UpdateEntryAsync();
```

or

```
foreach (var genre in genres)
{
    await client.For<User>("ApiUser").Key(user).LinkEntryAsync(genre);
}
```

The first operation could have been written in a more efficient way:

```
await client.For<User>("ApiUser").Key(1).Set(new {Genres = genres}).UpdateEntryAsync();
```

That will generate HTTP PATCH instead of PUT with only Genres updated, but it looks like your OData service requires all mandatory properties to be sent on the entity being updated, so this won't work.

Last but not least: get the latest version (4.9.1) of Simple.OData.Client. It has a fix that is important for your scenario.

UPDATE. I tested your OData service, and it doesn't seem to have a proper support for addressing links. For example, if I test sample OData service, I can execute requests like http://services.odata.org/V4/OData/%28S%28ygi3rwu514y0a4ooybn3d1gc%29%29/OData.svc/Products%284002%29/Categories/$ref (note $ref segment that addresses Caterogories link so this URI can be used to post link updates). But if I execute request http://{your_service_uri}/ApiUsers%281%29/Genres/$ref then I get an error "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://partymag.azurewebsites.net/ApiUsers(1)/Genres/$ref'." As long as this link doesn't work on a server side you won't be able to use LinkEntryAsync or UnlinkEntryAsync but you can still use UpdateEntryAsync as I showed above.

UPDATE2. The version that uses UpdateEntryAsync executes fine but service doesn't update links, here is the result from Fiddler:

Generated URI: PATCH http://{your_service_uri}/ApiUsers(1)
PATCH payload:

```
{  "@odata.type":"#PMWeb.Models.Models.User",
"id":1,"Name":"Ege",
"LastName":"Aydin",
"Email":"{removed}",
"Password":"{removed}",
"Genres@odata.bind":[
    "http://{your_service_uri}/Genre(31)","http://{your_service_uri}/Genre(32)"
  ]
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://{your_service_uri}/$metadata#ApiUsers/$entity",
"id":1,
"Name":"Ege",
"LastName":"Aydin",
"Email":"{removed}",
"Password":"{removed}"
}
```

If I now check the content of User's genres, they are the same. Since generated payload is correct and the service accepted it, it must be something on the server that is not executed properly.

Comment: I updated it, however all of my properties are public. I tried
`foreach (var genre in genres)
{
    await client.For<User>("ApiUser").Key(user).LinkEntryAsync(genre);
}`

Now it gives an exception saying
`Response "{\r\n  \"error\":{\r\n    \"code\":\"\",\"message\":\"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'ht…"`

Comment: Did you try the first alternative (using UpdateEntryAsync)? That worked for me on your database. I will check the one that's failing for you.

Comment: "Linked collection for type [Genre] not found" It gives this exception as before. I am confused. What might be what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. You must still be using a previous version of the library. I had the same problem until I fixed the error and uploaded a new NuGet package (4.9.1). Now I no longer get an error as you can see in the update above.
2. Although the service accepts changes in the PATH or PUT request, it doesn't seem update links. You should check the service.
3. As I wrote in the update, the service doesn't accept $ref format, and it should. This might be a source of your problem.

Comment: Well, i am pretty sure i updated it. Because when I saw your comment about the update, i checked it and yes there was a update to version 4.9.1 and of course I updated it. well what should I do? I am new to OData and Web services. So most terms are confusing to me. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: I just saw the edit on the answer. I will check, and return to you.

Comment: If the "Linked collection not found" error persists (which is mystery since it works for me), can you extract a small sample project that reproduces the error and send it to me?

Comment: @VagifAbilov I have a many-to-many relation for two objects. I am able to insert new objects into the Navigation Property, but if I pass an object that is already in the collection on the back end, I get an exception. Also, how would I remove an object from the Navigation Property without deleting the object from my database (just break the relation between the two objects)?